# How to display timestamped data with PrimeFaces and ChartJs?

Tags: primefaces, chart.js

Since the public 7.0 release of PrimeFaces includes ChartJs, I thought I'd give it a try.

It works fine, however so far I have not been able to properly display data with values changing over time in a line chart.

chart.js has cartesian time axes for this purpose, however in PrimeFaces , only CartesianLinearAxes is available.

Feeding date objects (instead of String labels) to ChartData simply results in no x-axis being drawn.

Am I missing something or did they just skip this functionality when including chart.js in Primefaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK great questions.

First, PF knows they did not implement time yet but there is an open ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4564

Second, have no fear you can use the Extender feature to make it work.  Here is an example we used.

1. In your Java model for your chart set the Extender feature on.

```java
chartModel.setExtender("chartExtender");
```

2. In your XHTML add this JavaScript code function to match when you set in #1 Java bean.

```js
function chartExtender() {
   //copy the config options into a variable
   var options = $.extend(true, {}, this.cfg.config);

   options = {
      //remove the legend
      legend: {
         display: false
      },
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            type: "time",
            time: {
               parser: 'h:mm:ss a',
               tooltipFormat: 'h:mm:ss a',
               unit: 'hour',
               displayFormats: {
                  'hour': 'h:mm:ss a'
               }
            }
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: {
               display: true,
               labelString: 'Your Y Axis',
               fontSize: 13,
            }
         }]
      }
   };

   //merge all options into the main chart options
   $.extend(true, this.cfg.config, options);
};
```

You can see the different time formats available from [ChartsJS using MomentJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats).

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising! I was unable to get it to work however - the extender function is getting executed on view load but the settings are not being applied. No scale labels, no colors... and no errors on the js console. I am using Strings for the labels of the data points, formatted according to the format given as 'parser' value in the extender, is this the correct way? Many thanks for helping me out!!

Comment: Never mind, it is working now. Instead of making a copy of the options object, I manipulated this.cfg.config directly in the extender, exchanging only the scales. Maybe your solution is working because of something specific to your project?

Comment: Yep that is why I make a copy of it and merge it back in!

Comment: Ok I see. Could you modify your answer so that it leaves project specifics out? I'll gladly accept it then! In any case, thanks alot for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: OK I think I stripped enough out to make it not specific!

Answer (score 1):

Just a complement to do the extender works, use *this.cfg.config.options = {...*

for exemple:

```
function extName() {
    this.cfg.config.options = {
        legend: {
           display: false
        }                    
    };
};
```